# Unpredictable DOCKER_HOST in Windows 11

Tags: windows, docker

I have the following issue which is persists for weeks now. When I start up my docker desktop on local windows machine and I open up a command line from total commander, I have some additional environment variables, for example a DOCKER_HOST which is not set in my environment variables. If I switch to another tab with command line in the new windows tool then the DOCKER_HOST is still there. If I open up a powershell window and type docker ps, then the connection is establishing and only the local things are visible. After this I can open up any new tab and the fantom DOCKER_HOST is not visible, BUT if I open up a new command line from total commander or native then the DOCKER_HOST is there again.

Do you have any idea what the hell is going on?

- I have checked registry and no DOCKER_HOST env found
- Disconneted from working vpn, DOCKER_HOST still there